# gcc linker - .obj dump has mixed source-assembly but not when linked in .elf

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, elf

**BACKGROUND**

I have a project using C-code and C++ code. The linking is not an issue: the C-functions are correctly called by the C++ code.

All my `.cpp` files are compiled with `-g3` but only `main.c` and `pyexec.c` are `-g3`; rest have no debug info.

The linking step consists of linking a few `.cpp` archives, `.cpp` objects and archive containing `.c` objects.

**PROBLEM**

When I do an `objdump` on my `.elf`

`objdump APP.elf -dSsxsgetr  > elf.dump`

I see the source of the `.cpp` files interspersed with the assembly but not for the two `.c` files compiled with `-g3`.

**DOUBLE-CHECK**

I am absolutely sure I compiled `main.c` and `pyexec.c` with `-g3`. When I did an [`objdump -dSsxsgetr`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html)`main.obj`, I see the source interspersed with the assembly in addition to debug symbols such as `.debug_line` that contains the entire source of my `.c` file.

My link command is:

`arm-none-eabi-ld.exe HW_Interface.obj HW_Module.obj HeapMngr.obj C_archive.a Cpp_archive.a -nostartfiles --no-warn-mismatch --gc-sections --stats --cref -Map=APP.map -T "APP.ld" -o "APP.elf"`

**QUESTION**

Why aren't the debug line numbers from the `.c` objects compiled with `-g3` getting into the `.elf`?

**UPDATE 1**

I think what's stripping the symbols is my linker-script statement combined with the `--gc-sections` option to the linker:

```
.dflash_code :
  {
    *ATI_micropython.dlb:*(.text.*) 
    *ATI_micropython.dlb:*(.debug*)

  } >dflash
```

This statement is "correct" but what is happening (I think) is that since I'm not explicitly specifying whatever input section contains the line-by-line info **and** because `--gc-sections` says *discard any "unused" sections*, that info is being stripped.

So the real question is: what's the input section I need to add to `.dflash_code` that contains the mixed source-assembly? The `.debug_line` section is already included and that contains the entire source for a given file.

In `.map`, there is a section called `Discarded input sections`. In this section, I see that only for my two `.c` debug files, there's a bunch of `.debug_macro` statements . . . which doesn't make sense because  `*ATI_micropython.dlb:*(.debug*)` should've caught all such sections (unless I'm misunderstanding their purpose).

```
.debug_macro   0x00000000       0x3a ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x35 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x3a ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x52 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x19 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000      0x189 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x10 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x22 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_macro   0x00000000       0x91 ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
```

Comment: Is it possible that whatever is placing the C object files into the library archive is stripping symbols?

Comment: @MichaelBurr no because to check the `.obj`s, I unzip the library archive but I think I know what is stripping the symbols; see my update shortly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr updated

Comment: I realize it may be difficult for an issue like this, but posting a [MCVE] would help us to help you.

Comment: @Tim I think I'm doing the gruntwork. I just need help with knowledge of `gcc` like my update: `what's the input section I need to add to .dflash_code that contains the mixed source-assembly?`

Comment: @Tim it's obvious that the info is being stripped from the `.obj` when the `.elf` is created and the linking process is doing it which is controlled by linker file and `ld` command line options.

Comment: @MichaelBurr if you're interested, figured it out.

Comment: @Tim if you're interested, figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the reason but I still don't understand **why** this happens:

In the linker file, if I place all sections with `.debug` in their name like `.debug_macro` in a different section:

```
  .dflash_code :
  {
    *archive.dlb:*(.text.*)
    *archive.dlb:*(.debug*)     
  } >dflash
```

Then in the ELF `.map` file I will get those sections placed in the `.elf` (no duh) including `.debug_line` which, in the `.obj`s, contains the entire source of the corresponding `.c`:

app.elf.map:

```
 .debug_line    0x1001841d      0x87e ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_line    0x10026152      0x8fe ..\archive.dlb(pyexec.doj)
```

However, if I run `objdump -Sxg app.elf`, I do NOT get the source intermixed with assembly:

```
Disassembly of section .dflash_code:
10000000 <micropython_main>:
10000000:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
10000002:   b084        sub sp, #16
10000004:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
10000006:   6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
10000008:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
1000000a:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (10000030 <micropython_main+0x30>)
1000000c:   f107 020c   add.w   r2, r7, #12
10000010:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
10000012:   f001 ff6d   bl  10001ef0 <mp_init>
10000016:   4807        ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; (10000034 <micropython_main+0x34>)
10000018:   f006 f88e   bl  10006138 <pyexec_frozen_module>
1000001c:   f001 ff94   bl  10001f48 <mp_deinit>
10000020:   f04f 0300   mov.w   r3, #0
10000024:   4618        mov r0, r3
10000026:   f107 0710   add.w   r7, r7, #16
1000002a:   46bd        mov sp, r7
1000002c:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
1000002e:   bf00        nop
10000030:   1fff34fc    .word   0x1fff34fc
10000034:   100313bc    .word   0x100313bc
```

---

However, if I change the linker file such that the `.debug*` sections from `archive.dlb` are not placed in `.dflash_code` (and I reiterate this is the **only** change I make):

```
.dflash_code :
  {
    *archive.dlb:*(.text.*)

  } >dflash
```

Then in the ELF `.map` file, I still see those same `.debug_line` sections however they are placed in a different location because of some other statements later in the my linker file

app.elf.map:

```
 .debug_line    0x00082a32      0x87e ..\archive.dlb(main.doj)
 .debug_line    0x000832b0      0x8fe ..\archive.dlb(pyexec.doj)
```

and most importantly, running `objdump -Sxg app.elf` gives the intermixed source-assembly

```
int micropython_main(char * uP_heap, unsigned int heap_size)
{
10000000:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
10000002:   b084        sub sp, #16
10000004:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
10000006:   6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
10000008:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
    int stack_dummy;
    stack_top = (char*)&stack_dummy;
1000000a:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (10000030 <micropython_main+0x30>)
1000000c:   f107 020c   add.w   r2, r7, #12
10000010:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
    #if MICROPY_ENABLE_GC
        gc_init(uP_heap, uP_heap + heap_size);
    #endif
    mp_init();
10000012:   f001 ff6d   bl  10001ef0 <mp_init>

    pyexec_frozen_module("main.py");
10000016:   4807        ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; (10000034 <micropython_main+0x34>)
10000018:   f006 f88e   bl  10006138 <pyexec_frozen_module>

    mp_deinit();
1000001c:   f001 ff94   bl  10001f48 <mp_deinit>

    return 0;
10000020:   f04f 0300   mov.w   r3, #0
}
10000024:   4618        mov r0, r3
10000026:   f107 0710   add.w   r7, r7, #16
1000002a:   46bd        mov sp, r7
1000002c:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
1000002e:   bf00        nop
10000030:   1fff34fc    .word   0x1fff34fc
10000034:   1001eaf4    .word   0x1001eaf4
```

So why does it matter where I put the sections `.debug*`? I don't think it technically does. The portion of my linker file that affects the placement of the DWARF symbols looks like this:

```
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
```

I'm guessing the ordering somehow matters.

Comment: Glad you found a solution - linker scripts are largely voodoo to me.